# Trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Toshiba Satellite laptop with Windows 10

Tags: system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Toshiba Satellite U940-103 laptop. It came with Windows 8 pre-installed and I then upgraded it to Windoes 8.1 and finally Windows 10. I tried mounting the .iso downloaded on [this page](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on two different usb drives using both rufus and UUI but i always got stuck on the third step of [this guide](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop). I would choose the first option: "erase disk and install Ubuntu" but I get automatically redirected to the "something else" page from the "second step" and I can't do anything even on this page. I don't care for dual boot. I'd like to completely remove Windows from the computer and install Ubuntu.

I mounted the .iso file on the USB drives on another computer with Windows 7, I don't know if that may be the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: @waltinator I'm not attempting dual booting, I'm trying to remove Windows while installing Ubuntu. But I have to admit you are right about confusion and frustration.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your computer is booting in UEFI mode. Most computers have it set by default, but some come with legacy mode selected. You can check in the BIOS of your computer.
When you get to the menu where you choose what to do, make sure you do choose "Something else". From this menu, delete all the partitions on your hard drive, and make one EXT4 and select the mount point as /
Then click on next. It will tell you that you have not created any swap, but it should be fine, especially if you have a decent amount of RAM. Then just proceed with the installation as normal.